# Build failed: the getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter

I am using snackbar to display the toast in my flutter app. Now, when I am running the app, I am a build failed error:

The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
../…/lib/fluttertoast.dart:155

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.

I do not get why because I am not using fluttertoast plugin anywhere in my application.

Please see my code below:

```
  void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      backgroundColor: SSColours.primary,
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

May you please help, thanks.

Comment: can you include where you've define `_showSnackBar`

Comment: Which Flutter version are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution. After doing much investigation, I found out there was nothing wrong with my code, I just needed to upgrade my flutter to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

I had the same issue. The issue appeared when importing a dart file from an external dependency that contains a wrong minimum dart version.

The dependency has code requiring a higher dart version than it says.

You have **two solutions**:

1. Downgrade the package version until the problem disappears
2. Upgrade your flutter version to a version where it matches the accurate minimum dart version of the package

**Which one to choose?**

- 1 is better if you do not want to upgrade the Flutter version because of the work to do so (packages migration if possible, code migration...)
- 2 is better if you need this specific version of the package (this version contains something you need)

### In-depth explanation

My situation was flutter 3.3.5 / dart 2.18.2
I wanted to use the `rate_my_app`. The package versions tab tells me this:

- 2.0.0 -> Min Dart SDK: 3.0
- 1.1.4 -> Min Dart SDK: 2.12

Since I use `flutter 3.3.5` and `dart 2.18.2`, I cannot use the 2.0.0 version of this package.
Let's use the 1.1.4 since 2.18.2 > 2.12

`flutter pub get` is ok since there is no version conflict.
**But the thing is, the package is lying to me.**

**Why is that?**

Well, if you open the package code (version 1.1.4), there are multiple uses (one is enough) of `context.mounted` which is something introduced in Flutter 3.7 that requires dart 2.19.0. Therefore the package pubspec.yaml indicates: `sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'`. It should have been `sdk: '>=2.19.0 <3.0.0'`

**What is the solution?**

If you have to use this specific package, one solution is to keep continuing to downgrade the package version until you find one that does not lie to you.

In my case, I had to replace

```
rate_my_app: ^1.1.4
```

by

```
rate_my_app: 1.1.3
```